# Formatear monedas VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, numberformat, ms-access-2013

¡Buenos Días!

Tengo un problema con la obtención de decimales enteros ',00', planteo mi problema por si a alguien le ha pasado y sabe como echarme una mano.

Mi problema es el siguiente, en VBA tenemos un tipo de dato llamado 'Currency' que, hasta donde se supone, se utiliza para almacenar valores que tengan decimales (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type) pero no consigo obtener los decimales ',00' es decir: 100,00 o 158,00.

Esto lo necesito ya que en la BBDD que estoy desarrollando el campo en cuestión almacena dinero y este puede ser tanto 99,32 como 123,45 o 100,00. Ahora bien, para realizar consultas de actualización en SQL se separan los campos por ',' y, de igual forma, los decimales, según mi configuración regional, también, por lo que tengo que utilizar comillas simples para introducir estos valores en la consulta ya que sino VBA interpreta que son campos diferentes.

```
PrecioVenta = DLookup("[Precio Venta]", "Articulos", "[Articulos.idart] =" & Me.idart)

Descuento = DLookup("Descuento", "Articulos", "[Articulos.idart] =" & Me.idart)

sqlPedido = "UPDATE Stock SET Stock.[Precio Venta] = '" & PrecioVenta & "', Stock.Descuento = '" & Descuento & "' Where Stock.Id = " & Me.SalidaId
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlPedido
```

Como se puede ver en el snippet anterior, la variable 'PrecioVenta' obtiene del campo '[Precio Venta]' el precio en cuestión en función de un id, el caso es que cuando ese valor es 100,32 o 84,34 funciona perfectamente ya que VBA pilla los decimales y entra en la consulta, ahora bien, cuando el precio es entero como 100,00 o 43,00 ya no, ahí simplemente coge la parte entera (100 o 43) y no me coge el ',00' por lo que, en la consulta, el valor 100 entre comillas simples ya es un String que no coincide con el tipo de la columna a actualizar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener siempre los decimales?

He probado la función Format() (entre otras muchas configuraciones) pero estamos en las mismas, devuelve un String formateado con ',00' pero al pasarlo a Currency desaparecen los ',00' y se queda solo la parte entera.

Muchas Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Matemáticamente los decimales a la derecha no tienen sentido si son todo ceros, por eso los omite pero sigue siendo un valor numérico. Aunque lo metas como entero., si lo estás guardando en un campo Currency y tienes configurados bien los decimales, entonces al salvar el valor se almacenará con 2 decimales. En cualquier caso te da igual porque los ceros decimales son solo un efecto visual, siempre puedes luego arreglarlo con formato en el propio campo. No afecta bajo ninguna circunstancia a la programación.